# Doubts about the address of the tensor on GPU

Tags: python, c++, libtorch

I used C++ and libtorch to debug tensor calculation.

I put a tensor on the GPU and define its pointer and output its address. And next, I defined another pointer to point a numcpp array and output their address. The code as follows:

```
torch::Tensor tensor = std::get<1>(max_out).to(at::kCUDA);
nc::NdArray<long> np = nc::zeros<long>(10, 20);
...
cout << "tensor address in function: " << &tensor << endl;
cout << "np address in function: " << &np << endl;
```

I found their addresses are close to each other as follows. In fact, *tensor* is on CUDA, *np* is on CPU. Is the address of CUDA on GPU have been mapped to the memory?

[image]

Comment: You are printing the address of two host variables. Obviously they will be close to one another in host memory. The fact that one might internally store an address in GPU memory is irrelevant and won't have any effect on what you are printing out

Comment: Couldn`t I print the GPU memory address of the defined tensor?

Comment: Probably yes, but your code is not how that would be done

Comment: Can you give me one example about printing the GPU memory address? Thanks.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classat_1_1_tensor.html#_CPPv4I0ENK2at6Tensor8data_ptrEP1Tv